# Passing notification data from App Delegate to View Controller with NSNotificationCenter using Swift 3 and Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm successfully receiving data from remote notification payload `userInfo` in my AppDelegate. Now I'm trying push to the View Controller from Storyboard, pass data to it, and update a variable using `NSNotificationCenter` but am receiving error:

```
Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values
```

in `viewDidLoad`. Thanks for taking a look!

(ObjC) AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    NSDictionary *roomKey = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"custom"] objectForKey:@"a"] objectForKey:@"roomKey"];
    NSLog(@"%@", roomKey);
    // Successfully prints correct roomKey, now need to pass to view controller and update variable. 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushToFollowers" object:nil userInfo:roomKey];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"audience"];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

    // line below is involved in optional crash
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

(Swift 3) VC:

```
import UIKit
import SocketIO
import IHKeyboardAvoiding

@objc class AudienceViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!

    var room: Room!

    var player: IJKFFMoviePlayerController!
    let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: Config.serverUrl)!, config: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true)])

    var overlayController: LiveOverlayViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.notificationArrived(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "pushToFollowers"), object: nil)
        // Optional error occurs on next line
        let urlString = Config.rtmpPlayUrl + room.key
        player = IJKFFMoviePlayerController(contentURLString: urlString, with: IJKFFOptions.byDefault())
        player.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        player.view.frame = previewView.bounds
        previewView.addSubview(player.view)
        player.prepareToPlay()
        socket.on("connect") {[weak self] data, ack in
            self?.joinRoom()
        }
    }

    // function isn't firing
    @objc func notificationArrived(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print(notification.userInfo!)
        if let custom = notification.userInfo?["custom"] as? [String: Any] {
            if let a = custom["a"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let roomKey = a["roomKey"] as? String {
                    print(roomKey)
                    room.key = (roomKey) as String
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting the notification way before the view controller calls `viewDidLoad()` and becomes an observer. That is the reason why the `notificationArrived(_:)` method doesn't fire.
But the crash is actually happens because you are not initializing the `room` property before you try to use it.

So when it tries to access the `room.key` not only the key value hasn't been set, the `room` is not initiated either.

What you could do instead is create a `Room` instance and pass it to the `AudienceViewController` through property after you instantiate it from the storyboard, and **then** use it once the controller's view is loaded.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"audience"];
Room *room = ... ; // create a room
room.key = roomKey;
viewController.room = room;
```

**AudienceViewController**

```
@objc class AudienceViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    @objc var room: Room!

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // if you are not planning on reusing this view controller for other rooms
        // then there's no reason for it to become an observer 
        let urlString = Config.rtmpPlayUrl + room.key
        ...
    }

    // notificationArrived(_:) is not needed anymore
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @lësha-turkowski! Implementing your solution took a bit of time as I'm learning iOS and had to solve another issue to get it working.  In my model.swift file I had to rewrite a swift Struct so it was visible to objective c. Here's the following code if it's helpful to someone else:

Comment: `struct Room {
    
    var key: String
    var title: String
    
    init(dict: [String: AnyObject]) {
        title = dict["title"] as! String
        key = dict["key"] as! String
    }
    
    func toDict() -> [String: AnyObject] {
        return [
            "title": title as AnyObject,
            "key": key as AnyObject
        ]
    }
}` converted to -->

Comment: `@objc public class Room: NSObject { var key: String = "" var title: String = "" convenience init(dict: [String: AnyObject]) { self.init() title = dict["title"] as! String key = dict["key"] as! String } func toDict() -> [String: AnyObject] { return [ "title": title as AnyObject, "key": key as AnyObject ] } }`